# Nested describe blocks with nested beforeAll/afterAll methods in ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, rspec, scalatest

We are trying to translate all our old RSpecs into ScalaTest `FunSpec`. We have run into a problem with nesting `describe` blocks.

In RSpec, each nested `describe` block can have its own `before/after(:all/:each)` blocks added to the outer scope. This is a very useful thing to be able to do, and we have made good use of it. Unfortunately, ScalaTest can only have `before/afterAll/Each()` methods at the root level of the test class, thus not being nestable.

*Is there a workaround for this?*

**RSpec:**

```
describe 'A person with two email addresses' do
  before(:all) do
    # create data
  end

  after(:all) do
    # delete data
  end

  it 'should have two phone numbers' do
    # ...
  end

  describe 'and one email address is retired' do
    before(:all) do
      # change some settings
    end

    it 'should be able to delete a retired email address' do
      # ...
    end

    it 'should not be able to retire the other email address' do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```